# How fix number of connection for heroku staging DataBase

Tags: heroku

I'm using heroku to deploy my Rails 2.3.6 application.I'm using production Database backup for my staging server.But when i using this command for restart heroku.

```
            heroku restart --app gentle-gorge-9319
```

after restart heroku when i reresh application home page i have this message in heroku logs

```
          remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication 
           superuser   connections + heroku staging error
```

How i can increase connection pool for staging server.

Any help will be more appreciated...

Thanks